# What are Islam's words about people with disabilities?

Tags: reward

Some people like me have light or heavy disabilities when they born. I know that Quran do not make any special difference between them and others except in contributing in wars.

But I heard somewhere a Hadith that disabilities clear some sins of the person who have this disability.

In general, does Islam have something special not-physical reward for people with disabilities? e.g. clearing some of their sins not contributing in wars which is physical!

Or will God reward them with special gift after death because of their patient with disabilities?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Allah says in Surah Baqarah:

> Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity. ([Surah Baqarah, verse 286](http://www.quran.com/2/286))

That means that you have the ability to cope with your disability. Also, our beloved prophet (peace and salawaat upon him) said:

> The pen has been lifted from three: From the sleeper until he wakes
>   up, from the minor until he grows up, and from the insane until he
>   comes back to his senses or recovers. ([Collected by An-Nasaa'i](http://sunnah.com/urn/1034430))

Other than alluding to the fact that insanity is treatable and recoverable, this talks about sin: the "pen being lifted" means that the person is not accountable for their actions. If they reach a sufficient level of disability, they are not liable to pray, fast, etc. because they don't have the mental capacity for doing so. So Allah, Al-Adl (the one who is ultimately just) does not hold them accountable.

Also, he (salallahu alayhi wa sallam) said in another hadith:

> There is nothing (in the form of trouble) that comes to a believer
>   even if it is the pricking of a thorn that there is decreed for him by
>   Allah good or his sins are obliterated. ([Saheeh Muslim](http://sunnah.com/urn/262410))

In fact, in the case of epilepsy specifically, another hadith clarifies the reward:

> A woman came once to the Prophet (Pbuh) and said: “I suffer from
>   severe epilepsy and parts of my body get exposed. Will you please pray
>   Allah for me?” The Prophet (Pbuh) said to her: “The choice is yours:
>   You may wish to endure it with patience and have admission into heaven
>   as your reward, or you may wish me to pray Allah to cure you.” She
>   said: “I will endure it, but some parts of my body get exposed, so
>   pray Allah for me not to be exposed.” The Prophet (Pbuh) prayed for
>   her. ([Bukhari and Muslim](http://www.islamicvoice.com/september.97/hadi.htm))

In this case, specifically, a great reward was outlined for the sufferer or epilepsy. No doubt that similar rewards also apply to other afflictions and disabilities. And Allah knows best.

Answer (score 3):

God is *righteous* and it's indeed one of His names. So people are asked about what they have done due to their abilities. Less ability means less duty which is always a good thing. That's why a blind person will not be asked about what sins he/she has done with his/her eyes.

God says in Quran (Al-kahf, verse 49):

> [...] And not one will thy Lord treat with injustice.

Answer (score 0):

In a sense, all men and women, compared to the divine reality are disabled; the term usually used is poor; we can equally say, weak; for men are born in weakness and die in weakness; and when they attain their first maturity their youthful vigour, understands as it is from the human viewpoint, blinds them to their essential poverty as compared to Allah, who is the support and the maintainer of all.

Generally speaking, there is a lighter burden of salat and fasting during Ramadan for the disabled. Obviously, this very much depends upon the disability. For example, for a man or woman who is seriously mentally disturbed has no obligations.